# Unable to use intersect in SUP iOS Object API application

Tags: ios, objective-c, sup

We are having problems using the SUPQuery function intersect in our SUP Object API project.
The two queries are executing fine by them self. They are even working using the union/unionAll functions. But when trying to intersect the both, an exception occurs:

```
SUPPersistenceException: -131 (ERROR) %1:intersect
```

[image]

Looking at the error constant, SYNTAX_ERROR, the query is malformed (Even though they are working fine one-by-one and in a union..).

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
SUPQuery * query1 = [SUPQuery getInstance];
query1 = [query1 select:@"t.*"];
query1 = [query1 from:@"X_MBO":@"t"];
SUPCompositeTest * innerCompTest1 = [SUPCompositeTest getInstance];
[innerCompTest1 add:[SUPAttributeTest contains:@"t.CUSTOMER":@"C1"]];
[query1 setTestCriteria:(SUPTestCriteria *)innerCompTest1];
SUPQueryResultSet * oList1 = [myDB executeQuery:query1];
NSLog(@"oList1: %@",oList1);

SUPQuery * query2 = [SUPQuery getInstance];
query2 = [query2 select:@"QT.*"];
query2 = [query2 from:@"Y_MBO":@"QT"];
SUPCompositeTest * innerCompTest2 = [SUPCompositeTest getInstance];
[innerCompTest2 add:[SUPAttributeTest contains:@"QT.CUSTOMER":@"C1"]];
[query2 setTestCriteria:(SUPTestCriteria *)innerCompTest2];
SUPQueryResultSet * oList2 = [myDB executeQuery:query2];
NSLog(@"oList2: %@",oList2);

//Query1 & Query2 both are returning a record each

SUPQuery *query3;
if (!oList1 && oList2) {
    query3 = query2;
}
else if (oList1 && !oList2) {
    query3 = query1;
}
else {
    query3 = (SUPQuery*)[query2 intersect:query1];
}
```

When executing the line below the error 131 occurs.

```
    SUPQueryResultSet * oList3 = [myDB executeQuery:query3];
```